# MongoDB/PyMongo How to delete a concrete item from array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, twitter, pymongo

Im new in MongoDB and Text process.
I have a database with a parsed tweets.
Example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b24aa1a0c99b0b85732406"),
    "idt" : "906060929829183489",
    "tweet" : [
        "RT",
        "@moocowpong1",
        ":",
        "@whitequark",
        "isn't",
        "the",
        "cloud",
        "just",
        "your",
        "data",
        "relocating",
        "to",
        "san",
        "francisco"
    ],
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-09-08T07:45:34Z"),
    "userName" : "Fiora Aeterna",
    "userLocation" : "San Jose, CA",
    "geo" : null,
    "geoCoord" : null,
    "Lang" : "en",
    "retweet_count" : 0,
    "sentimiento" : "",
    "score_tag" : ""
}
```

I tokenized the words in the tweet.
My next step is to delete stopwords.

My Code:

```
for doc in tweets.find({},{'tweet': 1}).limit(1):
    print (doc)
    for term in (doc['tweet']):
        if set(stop).intersection(term.split()):
            print ("Found One")
            tweets.update( { 'idt': doc['_id'] }, { '$pull': { 'tweet': { '$eq': term } } } )
```

`stop` is an array with stopwords.
I would like to remove the item from the tweet's array but my code fail with:

> raise WriteError(error.get("errmsg"), error.get("code"), error)
>   pymongo.errors.WriteError: unknown top level operator: $eq

I'm not sure if my update is correct, can you help me?

My final objetive is the register like (similar):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b24aa1a0c99b0b85732406"),
    "idt" : "906060929829183489",
    "tweet" : [
        "@moocowpong1",
        "@whitequark",
        "cloud",
        "just",
        "data",
        "relocating",
        "san",
        "francisco"
    ],
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-09-08T07:45:34Z"),
    "userName" : "Fiora Aeterna",
    "userLocation" : "San Jose, CA",
    "geo" : null,
    "geoCoord" : null,
    "Lang" : "en",
    "retweet_count" : 0,
    "sentimiento" : "",
    "score_tag" : ""
}
```

Comment: Update the error:     raise WriteError(error.get("errmsg"), error.get("code"), error)
pymongo.errors.WriteError: unknown top level operator: $eq

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$in`operator not `$eq`. So you don't need to control each stop word in a for loop. You can give all stop words at once and pull all of them in one query like this:

`db.collection.update({}, { $pull: { "tweet": { $in: ["stopWord1", "stopWord2"] } } } )`